# C# - How to convert string to timeStamp for insert into mysql

Tags: c#, string, timestamp

I'm using C# and Mysql database.
How to convert string to timestamp for insert into mysql? For example, I have string:
`28.9.2015 05:50:00`

Comment: Welcome to stack, tje rule is simple, you try something but got stuck or false result then you show us what u did and then we try to help point out your mistake  and not solve the entire problem for you

Comment: @KumarSaurabh I am a PHP programmer and the programming language C # I am new. PHP String conversion to Time Stamp in there. But I want to know how to do this in C #

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is what you need:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("28.9.2015 05:50:00", "dd.M.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify your required format and convert to datetime like this

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find what so difficult here... simply use the `DateTime.Parse` method

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("28.9.2015 05:50:00");
```

Not sure if it would work but try this

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("28.9.2015 05:50:00", "dd.M.yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you can insert it into your database as a `date` type.

Goodluck.

Comment: I get this error: `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: @AHIR when do you get this exception? after the conversation of when you insert it into your db?

Comment: This error is received before the insert to the database

Comment: @AHIR what's the exact  type of the column in your db?(e.g int , text etc)

Comment: The Column type is timestamp but this error when displayed string changint to dateTime in this line `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("28.9.2015 05:50:00");`

Comment: DateTime.Parse uses current culture, if in current culture dates are not represented as the input string it will throw exception

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.ParseExact:

```
using using System.Globalization;

string date = "31/12/2018";
dateParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In query database:

```
using (MyAppContext c = new MyAppContext())
{
    foreach (DbValues dbValues in c.DbValues.Where(a=> a.Timestamp < dateParsed))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```